# Certificate expire after a day

Tags: xcode

When I push a new build from Xcode to my iPhone, the certificate would expire after a day. Previously, it didn't happen this way. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Just a Guess: Since last XCode version it is possible to test apps on the device without purchasing an iOS developer account. Perhaps in this case an automatically certificate is generated which only lasts one day? If you have a developer account, try to renew your certificate.

Comment: yea you are right. Thanks!