# Unable to install my application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I have xcode 7.3.1 installed on my mac. Whenever I try install on real device , it says "The certificate used to sign 'my application' either expired or has been revoked. An updated certificate is require to sign and install application".

I can solve this issue in many ways like below

1.Delete revoked certificate from keychain and Fix issue by xcode.

2.Delete revoked certificate from keychain and Revoke development certificate from apple account

2.1 Create CSR using keychain

2.2 Create new development certificate by uploading CSR to apple.

2.3 Download new development certificate and install into keychain

2.4 Re-generate provisioning profile and install locally

2.5 In project settings -> code signing -> select provisioning profile and run the application

But my problem is certificate expires EVERY DAY (DAILY). I have to do these steps daily to run my application into real device.

Can anyone tell me why this certificates expires daily ? Is there any solution to create permanent development or distribution certificates ?.

Comment: update your xcode first, xcode 8 is comming out soon and you are using 3.1! It might reslove your issue !!

Comment: I haven't seen such issue so far but try to add team in your xcode > general > identity it might help.

Comment: I have a team already added. but still facing the same issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865235/certificate-expire-after-a-day
check this

Comment: Now certificate want required to run on real device while you are in development phase.

Comment: @PranavGupte I have already valid certificate in apple account.